# How to call Browsersync init banner programmatically?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

When Browsersync starts, it shows this banner to console:

```
[BrowserSync] Proxying: http://localhost:10623
[BrowserSync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:30623
    External: http://192.168.1.71:30623
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
```

I want to get it every time when my Gulp watcher is running, to get something like Webpack log.

Is there a way to get it? Or even some Gulp plugin to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify the reason for wanting to do this? It just looks like it is giving you the ports that the service is running on. If that is what you want, you should already know what ports a service is running on before it starts. If you want to show the whole banner for some reason, check the Browsersync documentation for displaying the startup banner and do that every time your Gulp watcher starts (If there is nothing in the docs, it may not be possible to manually display the banner) Hope this helps!